# "broken packages" when using apt-get

Tags: apt, libc6

I've tried to install MIME::Base64 with cpanm, which gives me the error that sys/types.h is missing.
I then try to install libc6-dev which fails with the error message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.13-38+deb7u8) but 2.19-11 is to be installed
             Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.13-38+deb7u8)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I hope someone knows a solution and can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you're trying to install a Debian 8 libc6 (2.19-11) on a Debian 7 system (2.13-38+deb7u8). Check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` for any strange entries.

Comment: After I changed the `etc/apt/sources.list` to the normal Debian mirrors it worked normal.